# Converting a frequency matrix to a list of ordered pairs in R

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say I have a 3x3 matrix of frequency values. Each cell in this matrix represents the number of entities detected at a certain location (the specifics about these locations don't matter for our purposes). For example, there were 0 entities detected in Row 1, Column 1; there were 3 entities detected in Row 2, Column 3; etc.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    0    1    1
```

I want to convert this matrix to an nx2 data frame, where n is the total number of entities detected in all locations. In this case, there should be 9 rows because there were a total of 9 entities detected. In the data frame we create, column 1 should contain the row index of the entity, and column 2 should contain the column index of the entity.

We can use the following code to accomplish this, but this method is pretty slow for larger matrices.

```
mat <- matrix(c(0,1,0,1,2,3,0,1,1), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
x <- rep(NA, 9)
y <- rep(NA, 9)
count <- 0
for(i in 1:3){
    for(j in 1:3){
        while(mat[i,j] > 0){
            count <- count + 1
            x[count] <- i
            y[count] <- j
            mat[i,j] <- mat[i,j] - 1
        }
    }
}
df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

This code gives us the following 9x2 data frame:

```
x  y
1  2
2  1
2  2
2  2
2  3
2  3
2  3
3  2
3  3
```

The way we interpret this data frame is by saying there was one entity detected at location (1,2), one entity detected at location (2,1), two entities detected at location (2,2), and so on. This output is correct, but I would prefer to use a faster method to obtain it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arr.ind parameter delivers the starting point, namely the indices that have non-zero entries and hten you can `rep()`-eat them by the entry values:

```
idxs <- which(dat > 0, arr.ind=TRUE)
idxs[ rep(1:nrow(idxs), dat[dat>0]), ]
      row col
 [1,]   2   1
 [2,]   1   2
 [3,]   2   2
 [4,]   2   2
 [5,]   3   2
 [6,]   2   3
 [7,]   2   3
 [8,]   2   3
 [9,]   3   3
```